# Please explain javascript function call in the below code snippet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, jquery, jsom

I am not able to understand how getWebs() function is called (highlighted below). What is the flow of execution for the below snippet. This code snippet works. Please also mention what it is called in Javascript.

```
function getWebs(success, error) {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var webs = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
    ctx.load(webs);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < webs.get_count(); i++) {
                var web = webs.get_item(i);
                result.push(web);
            }
            result.sort(compareByLastModifiedDate);
            console.log(webs);
            success(result);
        },
        error);
}

function compareByLastModifiedDate(a, b) {
    if (a.get_lastItemModifiedDate() < b.get_lastItemModifiedDate())
        return -1;
    if (a.get_lastItemModifiedDate() > b.get_lastItemModifiedDate())
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

//I unable to understand below highlighted code
**getWebs(function (webs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < webs.length; i++) {
            console.log(webs[i].get_lastItemModifiedDate());
        }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });**
```

Comment: As Danny'365CSI'Engelman already pointed out, this question is about basic JavaScript understanding. If you want to understand what code is doing, the [browser dev tools](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=browser+developer+tools&*) are really helpful. Use LogMessages and the debugger to understand the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var webs = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
```

specificies a null SPQuery, thus returns all the child webs

RTM:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getsubwebsforcurrentuser.aspx

## Learn JavaScript: http://superherojs.com/

Comment: Thanks Danny. This is not valid answer i am seeking. Please elaborate execution flow for the code snippet in question.

Comment: Its basic JavaScript. The function is called with 2 parameters which are function declarations, thus are named functions ``success`` and ``error`` inside the getWebs function

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. So basically we have function declaration as a parameter in a function call. Eg. functionName(function(webs){}, something)

Comment: Yes, You might want to take some time going through online JavaScript tutorials (type ``Javascript tutorial`` in Google). If you are going to ask every fundamental JS concept here on SO you won't be productive until 2020